# ZF2 on post update record (not working)

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to update records in my database. I am following a book but something isnt working.

This is the edit action. On post form action leads to process action.

```
    public function editAction()
{
    $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
    $user = $userTable->getUser($this->params()->fromRoute('id'));
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');

    $form->bind($user);

    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form,
        'user_id' => $this->params()->fromRoute('id')
    ));
    return $viewModel;

}
```

Process action

```
    public function processAction()
{
    // Get User ID from POST
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
    // Load User entity
    $user = $userTable->getUser($post->id);
    // Bind User entity to Form
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');
    $form->bind($user);
    $form->setData($post);
    // Save user
    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->saveUser($user);
}
```

And this is the class UserTable with function save user:

```
    public function saveUser(User $user)
{
    $data = array(
        'email' => $user->email,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'password' => $user->password,
    );
    $id = (int)$user->id;
    if ($id == 0) {
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    } else {
        if ($this->getUser($id)) {
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('User ID does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error showing. It passes $this->tableGateway->update and just nothing !

EDIT: I can delete users, add users.

Answer (score 1):

u miss this

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->saveUser($form->getData());
}
```

After validation you can now retrieve validate form data with $form->getData().
Also note that because of binding entity to form via $form->bind($user) $form->getData() is an instance of User
Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but i must check if form is valid.

```
if($form->isValid()){
// do the save 
}
```

Comment: Is your form has a filter class or some filter method in it?